# Blank Screen error while connecting the vncserver from SUSE-12 SP4 server

Tags: suse, vnc-server

While connecting the vncserver getting the blank screen.I have installed the vnc server in the SUSE-12 platform and while connecting the vncserver the log file has below error;

```
   vncext:      VNC extension running!
   vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on all interface(s), 
   port 5901
   vncext:      Listening for HTTP connections on all 
   interface(s), port 5801
   vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0

  ** (process:9295): WARNING **: Could not make bus activated 
  clients aware of XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME environment variable: 
  Could not connect: Connection refused
  gnome-session-is-accelerated: llvmpipe detected.
  gnome-session-binary[9295]: WARNING: Could not make bus 
  activated clients aware of GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is- 
  deprecated environment variable: Could not connect: Connection 
  refused
  gnome-session-binary[9295]: WARNING: Could not make bus 
  activated clients aware of XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome- environment 
  variable: Could not connect: Connection refused
  gnome-session-binary[9295]: WARNING: Could not make bus 
  activated clients aware of QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qgnomeplatform 
  environment variable: Could not connect: Connection refused
  gnome-session-binary[9295]: WARNING: Lost name on bus: 
  org.gnome.SessionManager
  Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

  ** (gnome-session-failed:9316): WARNING **: Cannot open display:
  /root/.xinitrc: line 1:  9295 Terminated              gnome- 
  session
```

I have followed below link for the installation of the vncserver;
https://www.dell.com/support/article/in/en/inbsd1/sln283107/how-to-install-and-configure-a-vnc-server-on-suse-linux-enterprise-server-sles-11?lang=en

Thanks in advance for help.

I have tried editing the .vnc/xstartup and also updated all the required packages, but it didn't work.
Right now my .vnc/xstartup  file has configuration as;

```
  #!/bin/sh

  unset SESSION_MANAGER
  unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
  export SESSION_MANAGER
  export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

 userclientrc=$HOME/.xinitrc
 sysclientrc=/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

  if [ -f "$userclientrc" ]; then
    client="$userclientrc"
  elif [ -f "$sysclientrc" ]; then
    client="$sysclientrc"
  fi

  if [ -x "$client" ]; then
      exec "$client"
  fi
  if [ -f "$client" ]; then
     exec sh "$client"
  fi

  [ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
  xsetroot -solid grey
  xterm -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
  if [ -x /usr/bin/icewm ]; then
   /usr/bin/icewm &
  else
   echo "No window manager found. You should install a window 
   manager to get properly working VNC session."
   fi
```